# Возможно ли удалить value с даного key в map`e?

Tags: java, map

Есть мапа такого формата:

`Map<Person, List<Pet>> map;`

```
public qweqwe() {
    this.map = new HashMap<Person, List<Pet>>();
}
```

Туда сохраняются ключи в которых есть несколько значений(Ключи - владельцы животных, значения - это кличка животного и вид(собака, кошка)).
Нужен метод который будет удалять конкретное животное с конкретного владельца.
Как его организовать?

Вот пример вывода map`ы для общего понимания:

```
Person [name=Yurii]
       Pet [nickname=Margo, vyd=Dog]
       Pet [nickname=Chita, vyd=Dog]
Person [name=qweqwe]
       Pet [nickname=Chita, vyd=Dog]
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

на Java 8:

```
void remove(Map<Person, List<Pet>> map, String name, String nickname) {
    Maps.filterKeys(map, person -> person.getName().equals(name)).forEach((person, pets) -> {
            pets.removeIf(pet -> pet.getName().equals(nickname));
    });
}
```

Правда, тут оверхед будет, если у вас имена животных уникальны. Вместо `pets.removeIf(pet -> pet.getName().equals(nickname));` можно тогда итератор использовать с условием выхода, если очень важен перфоманс.

**UPD:** без Guava будет так:

```
void remove(Map<Person, List<Pet>> map, String name, String nickname) {
    map.entrySet().stream().filter(person -> person.getName().equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())).forEach((person, pets) -> {
                pets.removeIf(pet -> pet.getName().equals(nickname));
    });
}
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9xf09k

От такие дела

Comment: @Yurii ой, этот метод из Guava.

Comment: @Yurii обновил ответ, если нет Guava.

Answer (score 3):

Первое что можно сделать, использовать иную реализацию `Map` и возможности ООП. Например из пакета com.google.common.collect взять `ListMultimap`, которая хранит в себе список вида `<K, Collection<V>>`. Использовать очень просто. Вначале создадим два класса `Person` и `Pet`:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof Person)) return false;
      Person person = (Person) o;
      return name != null ? name.equals(person.name) : person.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    }
  }

public class Pet {
    private String nickname;
    private String vyd;

    Pet(String nickname, String vyd) {
      this.nickname = nickname;
      this.vyd = vyd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof Pet)) return false;
      Pet pet = (Pet) o;
      if (nickname != null ? !nickname.equals(pet.nickname) : pet.nickname != null) return false;
      return vyd != null ? vyd.equals(pet.vyd) : pet.vyd == null;
    }
  }
```

Обращаю внимание, в классе `Person` переопределены методы `equals` и `hashCode`. В классе `Pet` переопределен метод `equals`.
Теперь создаем реализацию `Multimap`:

```
ListMultimap<Person, Pet> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

и заполняем данными:

```
Person personFirst = new Person("name1");
map.put(personFirst, new Pet("nick1", "vid1"));
map.put(personFirst, new Pet("nick2", "vid2"));
map.put(personFirst, new Pet("nick3", "vid3"));

Person personSecond = new Person("name2");
map.put(personSecond, new Pet("nick1", "vid1"));
map.put(personSecond, new Pet("nick2", "vid2"));
map.put(personSecond, new Pet("nick3", "vid3"));
```

теперь чтобы удалить `Pet` у `Person` нам необходимы всего лишь экземпляры этих классов:

```
map.remove(personSecond, new Pet("nick3", "vid3"));
```

Также `Map` можно получить в привычном виде:

```
Map<Person, Collection<Pet>> mapResult = map.asMap();
```

Если нет возможности использовать стороннюю библиотеку, то можно посмотреть на реализацию методов `put` и `remove` в `ListMultimap` и повторить в упрощенном виде:

```
public boolean put(@Nullable K key, @Nullable V value) {
   return this.get(key).add(value);
}

public boolean remove(@Nullable Object key, @Nullable Object value) {
   Collection collection = (Collection)this.asMap().get(key);
   return collection != null && collection.remove(value);
}
```